# How can I hide Paging in Kendo ui listview

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

How can I hide paging in kendo ui listview ? I mean bottom page number and navigation do't show

Answer (score 2):

Just don't add a pager or set a page size in the datasource. Then if you want it to scroll, set a height and the overflow:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: products,
});

$("#listView").kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
});

    #listView {
        height: 400px;
        overflow-y: auto;  
    }
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IlobOw)**